# login authentication using curl php

Tags: php, curl

I have tried this code for login authentication but its not working. Please help any one.

```
<?php
     define('URL', 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx.net/');
     function authenticate($uname, $pass) {

    $url = URL . 'Issue/Bug-5555';

    $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$uname:$pass");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // ssl ensure cert
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1); /// ssl ensure cert

    $issue_list = (curl_exec($curl));
    echo $issue_list;

    return $issue_list;
}   ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please could you provide more details about how your code is not working? Any error messages, etc. Additionally, please could you give details of what you've already tried to resolve the problem you're having.

Comment: What error you are geting?

Comment: The above code is i tried but i received only null values..

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to the /rest/api/ endpoint to query the JIRA API...

```
$url = JIRA_URL . 'rest/api/2/issue/Bug-5555';
```